# Wrong link pulled into report when recording an exact duplicate on another SE site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons, duplicates

When reporting [this question on SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/272337/i-am-using-a-memory-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk/272352#272352) as an exact duplicate of [this one over on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-a-memory-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why), the description of question 2868 on SF is pulled through, not the description of question 2868 on dba.se.

The comment that gets added was (before I applied an edit):

```
possible duplicate of [What is the best open-source email solution package](https://serverfault.com/questions/2868/what-is-the-best-open-source-email-solution-package)
```

rather than

```
possible duplicate of [I am using a MEMORY engine but MYSQL still writes to my disk…why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-a-memory-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why)
```

which I expected.

Is this behavior-as-intended (i.e. the feature is intended for marking duplicates within one site, and cross-posted duplicates should be reported some other way) or a bug?

As a side question: would it be worth implementing a distinction between questions from different users that carry the same meaning (which just want to be closed with a link to the older question) and cross-posts (in which case merging the answers, before closing the copies on all but the most relevant site, makes more sense)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of closing a question as a duplicate on another Stack Exchange site.

If a question is inappropriately cross-posted, flag it for moderator attention and it will be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this behavior-as-intended (i.e. the feature is intended for marking duplicates within one site, and cross-posted duplicates should be reported some other way)

Yes. In a general sense, it's actually *fine* to have questions "duplicated" across sites - provided they're addressing different audiences. Of course, if a question is off-topic, or if a user is simply re-posting the exact same question on multiple sites (cross-posting), it should be migrated to the site where it's most on-topic and dealt with there.

#### See also: [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)